# How can you develop on a live WordPress installation that is using W3 Total Cache?

Tags: theme-development, cache, customization, plugin-w3-total-cache

Or to make it easier: you just want to disable the caching in order to see your changes in realtime.

Any solution that would allow you to disable caching based on IP, logged user or cookie will be acceptable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has this natively: *Performance > Page Cache > General > Don't cache pages for logged in users*

You can always check if you are seeing cached page by looking at page source, W3 outputs status (commented out) at end of page.

Answer (score 2):

Also, I would recommend ***against*** developing on a live site.  Do all of your development on a private (i.e. local) installation of WordPress, then update your live installation and purge the cache.  Developing on a live site runs the risk of breaking something for users *while they're using the site!*

Comment: Generally I agree with you, but in same cases this is not possible. Also if you are only doing small changes like theme related ones working with two versions can also be a slowdown.

Comment: Can it potentially slow things down to work on two copies?  Yes.  Can forgetting to close a `<?php ?>` block in your theme file break your site and lock you out of WordPress until you manually disable the theme via FTP/phpMyAdmin?  Yes.  Generally, I think that particular risk outweighs the simplicity of modifying a live theme.